# Highcharts : hiding bottom-most x axis grid line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts for one of my stock project. Everything is okay except I could not hide the bottom grid line in x axis as shown in the attached image.[image: This image]

Updates: Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vgaJd/)

I have the following properties in my javascript:

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            maxZoom: 30 * 24 * 3600000,
            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            tickLength: 0,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%e'
            },
            labels: {
                y: 24,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '1.6em',
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    fontFamily: 'standardCondensed',
                    color: '#bcbdbd'
                }
            },
            plotLines : [{
                value : (function() {
                        // To Do ...
                    })(),
                color : '#39484d',
                dashStyle : 'solid',
                width : 32,
                label : {
                    text : ''
                }

            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
                title: {
                text:   ''
            },
            opposite: true,
            min: 0,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color:  '#808080'
            }],
            labels: {
                format: '${value}',
                y: 20,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '2em',
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    fontFamily: 'standardCondensed',
                    color: '#bcbdbd'
                }
            }
        },
```

Is there a way to hide that line but display the months numbers at the bottom?

Comment: I will make a guess here and say it has to do with the width or dash style? If those don't work, change the color to blend in with the background. - make a fiddle with some sample data and i will mess with it.

Comment: I am making a fiddle, I will post my fiddle asap.

Comment: Here is the fiddle I just made http://jsfiddle.net/vgaJd/ I need to hide all the horizontal grid lines but no the numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vgaJd/3/) is a fiddle with your solution. You needed to add:

```
            lineColor: 'transparent',
```

To each axis.

Comment: I have already tried that in my project. In your fiddle, I still see the last horizontal line, which I need to hide.

Comment: @jeewan if you could update your fiddle to be more like your project it would be much easier. I will keep trying different things though.

Comment: I have not included my CSS in the fiddle, so it looks different but it should not matter as I only need to hide the last bottom horizontal line which I think is related to configuring Highcharts' plugin's properties. (I have a background image set in my project as you see in the image but its not in the fiddle, that's why you are seeing the differences)

Comment: wow man, that worked. Thanks, I am accepting your answer in a few minutes :-) ... thank you so much.

Comment: I just figured it out that, you do not need to add those properties in yAxis, adding only in xAxis will work but one more property to update in yAxix is plotLines->width sould be set to 0. I removed those properties in yAxis and changed plotLines as 
plotLines: [{
                 value: 0,
                 width: 0, // it was 1 before
                 color:  '#808080'
             }],
Thanks again JordanD, have a great day :-)